# How to correctly use find with regular expression?

Tags: find, regular-expression

I cannot figure out the correct use of find with `-regex` option:

For example, given this example:

```
Morcheeba/Big Calm/02 Shoulder Holster.flac
Morcheeba/Big Calm/02. Shoulder Holster.flac
```

I only want to match the string in the form `path/to/file/## filename.ext`, without the dot.

I've tried with:

```
find Morcheeba/ -regextype egrep -iregex ".*[0-9]{2}*[a-z]*flac$"
```

and some variation, but I always get all files either none.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are mixing `.` and `*`. In your example, the second `*` could be a space and the third `*` should be a `.` or `\.`. You could use `[^\.]` to match any character that is not a period. Put a `*` after it to match 0 or more non-period characters.

Comment: can't reproduce, seems to work (even with that strange pattern)

Answer (score 6):

Note that `-regex`/`-iregex` (GNU extensions), like the standard `-path` match on the full path, not just the file name.

If you want to find files whose *name* (as opposed to *path*) starts with 2 decimal digits, following by something that is not a decimal digit and ending in `.flac`, you could do portably:

```
find . -name '[0-9][0-9][!0-9]*.[fF][lL][aA][cC]'
```

Note that it wouldn't match on `01.flac` because the `[!0-9]` can't match there. Instead you could write it:

```
find . -name '[0-9][0-9][!0-9]*' -name '*.[fF][lL][aA][cC]'
```

Those use wildcard patterns, not regexps.

To use GNU `find`'s `-iregex`, the equivalents would be:

```
find . -regextype egrep -iregex '.*/[0-9]{2}[^0-9/][^/]*\.flac'
find . -regextype egrep -iregex '.*/[0-9]{2}([^0-9/][^/]*)?\.flac'
```

That is, we anchor the two digits at the start, as we make sure the rest of the regexp doesn't span a `/`.

Comment: ahhh egrep, that must be what the -E switch is that everyone keeps talking about for the osx version. thanks.

Comment: @fie, yes, with BSD find, `-E` is the equivalent of GNU find's `-regextype egrep` or `-regextype posix-extended`. See `man find` for details. There's [a currently open feature request](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?42501) for that `-E` to be added to GNU find as it's arguably far less cumbersome to use.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @steeldriver, the regex `.*[0-9]{2}[^.]*\.flac` worked properly.

Comment: That would match on `./path/to/foo123.flac` or `./foo/1234/whatever.flac` though.

Comment: Yes, I had to fix it a bit.